# Как вызвать value из input-а и загнать его в условие?

Tags: php, wordpress, input, wordpress-плагины, value

Пишу плагин на wp. Задача вызвать как то **value** и загнать его в if для сравнения, ну и можно вывести на экран через echo, чтобы проверить результат. Пробовал делать через хук с функцией, но оно вызывает value пустым (снизу код). Помогите, в php недавно.

```
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_quantity_input_field', function ($input_value){
 

    echo $input_value;
    if($input_value > 1){
        $input_value + 1;
        echo $input_value;
    }

    return $input_value;

},10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю как работает WP, но мне кажется проще отправлять данные через форму или ajax и получить их через $_GET или $_POST. Будет что-то вроде

```
if(isset($_POST['input_name'])){
   echo($_POST['input_name'])
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, хотя идея неплохая(

Comment: Так, кое что подправил и вроде чет вышло, спасибо большое <3